# PHP Form - PHP Mailer cannot send to @Gmail.com

Tags: php

We have a PHP form on our website that has worked for years. When users fill the form out in sends us the details, and sends them an email and then re-directs the user to a "thank-you" page. However, if a user puts their email address as @gmail.com the form fails to send, it doesnt show the thank-you page.

This is really bizarre. We are using PHPMailer and validate if the form has been sent using:

```
 if($mail->Send()) {
      $mailsent = true;
```

If a user enters @hotmail.com or at @yahoo.com everything is fine. But enter @gmail.com and $mailsent is always false.

In this situation where does the problem lye? It seems to me that our web hosts SMTP connection to Gmail is failing. Would this seem right?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  $name = '';
  $email = '';
  $mailsent = false;
  $referer = '';

  if(isset($_POST['name'])){

  include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Quote request  from ' . $name;
    $body = 'A quote request has been received from a user with following details:' . "\n\n" .
            "Name: $name \n" .
            "Email: $email \n" .
            "----------------------------------------------------\n\n" .
            "Place: UK".

    $body .= "\n----------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    $body .= "Refering: ".$referer." \n";


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->From     = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress("dean@example.com", "Example");

    if($mail->Send()) {
      $mailsent = true;

    } else {
      $error[] = 'There was some error. Please try later.';
    }

  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged into the `Send()` method to see where exactly it fails?

Comment: check out PHPs error logs. You are likely to find more information there. Your host probably has PHPs error message turned off by default, which is why it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Nothing in the PHP error logs. I have the debugging on the PHP set to: 

`error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;`  But nothing is written to the page, or the logs :(

Comment: Post your code then, minus actual emails etc. Use `email@example.com` if needed.

Comment: Posted the code, just a bog standard PHPMailer implementation (I believe!)